# set up Power BI services on Azure to get a fixed IP address to connect to production MySQL Credentials for login

Tags: azure, powerbi, cloud, static-ip-address

I am really new to the Azure cloud platform and need some help setting up Power BI on Azure with a static IP address to add the address to my firewall. The production MySQL is in Hostgator to distribute among the organization to access analytics.

Comment: Can you please detail at what part is Snowflake involved?

Answer (score 0):

To control the IP used to connect to your database you must install a [Data Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) either in Azure or on some server you control, and configure the Dataset to use the Gateway to refresh.

Otherwise the IP addresses that may be used by Power BI are documented in the [Azure Service Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/service-tags-overview) list.  But they do change over time, so it's a hassle to use with any firewall that doesn't natively support Azure Service Tags.